# The request is sent but I get an error in console and does not run the script

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a table in which users are registered. When I give you to delete one what I want is to get a confirmation message and in case you click accept send me a request by ajax. I share my codes to observe:

```js
const eliminar=document.querySelectorAll('.delete'),
    tablaContactos=document.querySelector('#tabla-contactos');
//asignarles un evento mediante un bucle
eliminar.forEach(index => {
    index.addEventListener('click',eliminarUsuario);
});

function eliminarUsuario(e){
    /* Con la propiedad target podemos identificar a que elemento se le ha dado click */
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-eliminar')){    
        /* Para obtener una propiedad html utilizamos el metodo getAttribute */
        const id=e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        const data=new FormData();
        data.append('id',id);
        const respuesta=confirm('¿Estas seguro que deseas eliminar usuario '+id+'?');
        if (respuesta){
            
             // Creación del objeto
             const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
              
             // Apertura de la conexión y envío a través del metodo get
             xhr.open('POST','http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/eliminar',true);


             // Lectura de la respuesta
             xhr.onload=function(){
                  if(this.status===200){
                       const respuesta=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                       console.log(respuesta);
                       
                       if (respuesta.respuesta=='exito') {
                        mostrarNotificacion('Contacto eliminado correctamente','correcto');  
                       } 
                       else{
                        mostrarNotificacion('Hubo un error','error');  
                       }
                  }
             }

             //Envío de la petición
             xhr.send(data);
            
        }
        
    }
}

function mostrarNotificacion(mensaje,clase){
    //Creamos un div y posteriormente una clase
    const notificacion=document.createElement('div');
    //En javascript añadimos clase de la siguiente manera. Cabe destacar que podemos añadir mas de dos
    notificacion.classList.add(clase,'notificacion');
    //Dentro del div añadimos un texto con el metodo textContent.
    notificacion.textContent=mensaje;
    //añadimos el div en el formulario mediante insertBefore.
    tablaContactos.insertBefore(notificacion,document.querySelector('table'));

    /* Funcion para hacer animacion en javascript */
    setTimeout(()=>{
         notificacion.classList.add('visible');

         setTimeout(() => {
              notificacion.classList.remove('visible');
              setTimeout(() => {
                   notificacion.remove();
              }, 500);
         }, 3000);
    },100);
}
```

```css
public function deleteUser($id){
        $sql="DELETE FROM usuario WHERE idusuario=$id";
        $stmt=$this->db->query($sql);

        return $stmt;
    }
```

```html
public function eliminar(){
        Utils::isAdmin();
        if (isset($_POST)) {
            $objUsuario=new Usuario();
            $result=$objUsuario->deleteUser(intval($_POST['id']));
            if ($result){
                $respuesta=array(
                    'respuesta'=>'exito',
                    'id_eliminado'=>$_POST['id']
                );
            }
            else {
                $respuesta=array(
                    'respuesta'=>'error'
                );
            }

        }

        die(json_encode($respuesta));

    }
```

The query is actually running and the user is deleted, but in console I get this error:

```
VM1652:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (eliminar-usuario.js?v=1586222368:29)
xhr.onload @ eliminar-usuario.js?v=1586222368:29
load (async)
eliminarUsuario @ eliminar-usuario.js?v=1586222368:27
```

but when checking in the part of the console where the requests are shown I notice that if you receive the json coming from the php driver

[image]

Will I have an error in the controller?

Comment: Your PHP script is echoing HTML before the JSON. You need to fix it not to do that, it should only return JSON.

Comment: die(json_encode($respuesta)); something like this?

Comment: You already have that. Something else in your script is echoing HTML, you need to get rid of that.

Comment: it does not wok :(

Comment: Do you have `auto_prepend_file` enabled in your `php.ini`? You shouldn't use this to output HTML, because it breaks scripts like this.

Comment: it says: auto_prepend_file    Local value: novalue

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you still seeing HTML before the JSON in the Network panel?

Comment: Barmar how can l avoid it?

Comment: You have to find the part of your script that's echoing the dropdown-menu and get rid of it.

Comment: header.php is mi file

Comment: You're calling `http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/eliminar` in the AJAX.

Comment: yes l am this file

Comment: and i got Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/Facturacion/usuario/savefrt", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}